# .NET error trapping at application level?

Tags: .net, asp.net

Ive been reading about trapping .Net errors at page and application level and cant decide what best suites what I want to do.
All I want is a basic redirect to a page telling the users an error has occured, no matter what the error or what page its happened on (there will be some logging going on as well).
Should this be application level?

thanks

Comment: Don't you want to log those errors, so you have details about these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `customErrors` attribute to the web.config. It will redirect to specified pages on error:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorGeneric.html" mode="RemoteOnly">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error500.html"/>
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error404.html"/>
    </customErrors>
<system.web>
```

Further more, configure a logging framework that can help you storing error information for later analysis. Here are a few frameworks: [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [CuttingEdge.Logging](http://logging.codeplex.com/). I would advice you to use one of these frameworks instead of fiddling around in the `Application_Error` event and writing log functionality yourself.

Comment: This is the exact same as my answer, only I told you to use the IIS management console as it is simpler than editing in the Web.config directly, IIS management console edits the web.config for you.

Answer (score 0):

See the .NET Error Pages feature in Internet Information Server (IIS 7). Here you can add different error pages for different HTTP errors. Throw HTTP exceptions using the HTTP error code that you want for your error http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bazc3hww.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by catching th Application_Error event in your Global.asax. This is an example from MSDN:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the exception object.
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

    // Handle HTTP errors
    if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
    {
        //Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
        Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");
    }
    // For other kinds of errors give the user some information   
    // Log the exception and notify system operators 
    // Clear the error from the server
    Server.ClearError();
}
```

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx) for the complete example, and some general advise on the subject.